# Running / compiling jdbc-sqlite on OSX 10.5

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I can't for the life of me get the library located here: http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC and [zentus.com](http://zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) to run in native (JNI) mode on OSX 10.5.
If I query the driver for the mode it always says "pure", which means it's running in nested VM mode and pure java code is running to query the sqlite database, which is slower. I do however (and how obvious) want it to run in native mode, which is faster :)

I tried compiling it myself, but I'm either running into trouble that it can't find the sqlite library when running the unit tests (zentus) or the compile not finding dylib10.5.1.so (xerial).

Has running this jdbc driver in JNI mode on 10.5 ever been achieved? Both sources claim that it's possible...

Answer (score 0):

There is a new project [SQLJet](http://sqljet.com/) that is a pure Java implementation of SQLite. It doesn't support all of the SQLite features yet, but may be a very good option for some of the Java projects that work with SQLite databases.